# Background does not change onclick function

Tags: html, css, onclick

what's wrong with my code? For some reason my function load() does not change .firstDiv background?

I can't find any mistakes.

```js
function load() {
document.getElementsByClassName("firstDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/140945/pexels-photo-140945.jpeg')";
}
```

```css
.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100vh;
  float: left;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/200303/pexels-photo-200303.jpeg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
```

```html
<div class="firstDiv"></div>

<div class="secondDiv">
  <button onclick="load()">Change background</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. Didn't know that. So in general it is better to use id?

Comment: It depends on the use case. Use ID for unique elements and classes for multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("firstDiv")...
```

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an HTMLCollection like reported in the doc.

You need to change that line with:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("firstDiv")[0]
```

The snippet:

```js
function load() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('firstDiv')[0].style.backgroundImage
 = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/140945/pexels-photo-140945.jpeg')";
}
```

```css
.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}

.firstDiv {
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/200303/pexels-photo-200303.jpeg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="firstDiv"></div>
<div class="firstDiv"></div>

<div class="secondDiv">
    <button onclick="load()">Change background</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `load()` function, need to change it so that it uses the first element of `getElementsByClassName` since it returns multiple elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("firstDiv")[0]...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `getElementByClassName` then you need to specify the item number by specifying index like `[0]` OR alternatively use `id`

**Example with Class Name:**

```js
function load() {
document.getElementsByClassName("firstDiv")[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/140945/pexels-photo-140945.jpeg')";
}
```

```css
.firstDiv, .secondDiv {
  width: 50%;
  height:100vh;
  float: left;
}

.firstDiv {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/200303/pexels-photo-200303.jpeg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
```

```html
<div class="firstDiv"></div>

<div class="secondDiv">
  <button onclick="load()">Change background</button>
</div>
```

**For ID**

1. Assign ID e.g `<div id="firstDiv"></div>`
2. JS Code:

   ```
   document.getElementById("firstDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/140945/pexels-photo-140945.jpeg')";
   ```